# I need help locating Paypal ClientID and ClientSecret ID

Tags: api, paypal, sandbox

complete noob here.Any help is really appreciated because we are under the cosh.

My team is building out a bespoke donation form for a charity client and are trying to integrate Paypal.

The problem is that the api we are working with is requesting a Paypal ClientID and ClientSecret ID.

What is the best practice for getting these values? I've read that you have to set up a developer account via Paypal and then set up an app, however, does that mean we require access to their paypal account.

Can they grant limited access to their paypal account so we can create values?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: "developer account via Facebook". I'm confused, what does Facebook have to do with getting access to paypal client/secret ID's?

Comment: Apologies, a typo from my amend. Was supposed to read Paypal. Have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a sandbox account:

https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

This will create a dummy version with no real transactions that you'll have full access to, alongside a production version that only your client will see.

You can determine which of these accounts is used through env vars, switching out the client ID as needed depending on which environment you're performing the transactions on.

But at the end of the day, yeah, you will have access to their production client ID and client secret ID. There's no way to get these onto your server unless your client is able to do it themselves.

Comment: thanks for your help. It's much appreciated. Have a good weekend.